# Pandas - deviation from a fixed mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
   df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'Player':['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
                            'Goals':[1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                            'Assists':[2.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                            'ShotBar':[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                            'ShotDefended':[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                            'ShotOut':[3.0, 2.0, 0.0]})
```

---

**Aggregate**

Now I want to aggregate:

1. 'Goals' and 'Assists' under a **'Succeed'** column,
2. 'ShotBar', 'ShotDefended' and 'ShotOut' under a **'Miss'** column.

---

**Rules of the Game**

I'm bound to a rule that must apply specific weights to each feature:

- Goals: 8.0 points
- Assists: 5.0 points
- ShotBar: 3.0 points
- ShotDefended: 1.2 points
- ShotOut: 0.8 points

So, under these rules, the ratio **Succeed/Miss** is `13.0/5.0`, a fixed `2.6`.

Theoretically, if all values were `1.0`, after applying the ratio, over `2.6` the player is to considered productive, an under `2.6`, unproductive.

The highest deviation from this mean is the most productive player.

---

This is how I try to apply my weights to the dataframe:

```
df_temp['Succeed'] = df_temp['Goals']*8.0 + df_temp['Assists']*5.0
df_temp['Miss'] = df_temp['ShotBar']*3.0 + df_temp['ShotDefended']*1.2 + df_temp['ShotOut']*0.8 
df_temp['Iprod'] = (df_temp['Succeed']/df_temp['Miss']).replace(np.inf, 0).fillna(0)
```

Problem is that when the sum of values under 'Miss' concept is `0.0`, division `df_temp['Succeed']/df_temp['Miss']` will be zero, which is undesired.

```
  Player  Goals  Assists  ShotBar  ShotDefended  ShotOut  Succeed  Miss  Iprod
0    One    1.0      2.0      0.0           0.0      3.0     18.0   2.4    7.5
1    Two    0.0      0.0      1.0           1.0      2.0      0.0   5.8    0.0
2  Three    1.0      1.0      0.0           0.0      0.0     13.0   0.0    0.0   <------------
```

---

How do I fix that using pandas?

Are there any other statistical methods that could achieve my aim?

Comment: Would you consider setting a max value for Iprod and use that when Miss = 0? That might solve you problem. Otherwise, I'm not sure why you wouldn't use Succeed/(Succeed+Miss), but I'm not familiar with the metric you are trying to build.

Comment: yes I would consider. you can answer using such a conditional with max value.

Comment: Was my answer sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing infinity with some max value, say 1000. Then you would want to cap all Iprod values in case some other record exceeds 1000.

```
df_temp['Iprod'] = (df_temp['Succeed']/df_temp['Miss']).replace(np.inf, 1000).fillna(0)
df_temp['Iprod'] = df_temp['Iprod'].clip(upper=1000)
```

Comment: No, sorry, it messes with the metric.

Comment: Is the metric messed up because players without a miss probably don't have many successes, so those players are getting too high of a score?